# PDF processing library in Erlang

Tags: pdf, erlang

I am looking for a PDF processing library written in Erlang, but I was unable to find any yet. [ErlGuten](http://www.sics.se/~joe/erlguten-2.1/erlguten.html), the only library I found could only generate PDFs not process them.
Anyone aware of such library?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to bridge with a 3rd party PDF library. Such as Adobe's own PDF Library SDK or another lesser known vendor.

See; http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library/

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source library based on webkit: WKHTMLTOPDF
It generates PDF from an HTML template.

And here is [small tutorial](http://beebole.com/en/blog/general/convert-html-to-pdf-with-full-css-support-an-opensource-alternative-based-on-webkit/) of how we are using it whith an Erlang backend.

Comment: I cant get my head around if I think this sounds like an elegant solution. What happens if the sites are to long? Are they cut up in the same anoing way as when printing from the browser?

Comment: Soo Mic, Do you have another way? or do you just accept the the pdf gets dirty?

Comment: We show documents with tables. It is possible to calculate the size and insert a page break if needed, repeating the header. But since we have generally a one page document, we have other priorities to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Jinterface is the best way.Try to process PDFs with Java.